# CSS layout of a React app breaks when switching Portrait to Landscape

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

Is there any code that detects orientation switching on a real tablet device?

When I resize the browser using chrome tools/responsive/ipad, everything looks good and is responsive. However on a real tablet, layout breaks on orientation change.

I am not sure if this is a problem with

- CSS code
- Limitation with Material UI and the ability to switch orientation on a real device
- Something to do with meta tags

I have been struggling with this for days so finally posting here.

Here is the relevant code:

```
  <Head>
    <title>NotChinaDeals</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="minimum-scale=1, initial-scale=1, width=device-width" />
  </Head>
  <ThemeProvider>
    <CssBaseline />
  
    <header>
      <nav>
      <TopAppBar />
      </nav>
    </header>

      <main>{children}</main>
      
  </ThemeProvider>
```

Here is a visual of the issue

[image]

I am adding a link if you can see anything wrong with the meta tags (it will only be broken on a real tablet).
[Link to page showing the issue](https://notchinadeals.com/)

Comment: There is a keyword to detect orientation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/orientation , but I think the problem may be a difference between WebKit (the engine every browser uses on IOS/IpadOS) and Blink. I would try to connect the device to a computer and debug the css using the real device.